# The verb after conjugation in たり compound sentence, is still a verb? And if so, why is it despite する being the verb？

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, compounds, parts-of-speech

> 雨の日は滑ったり、転んだりする。

If する is the verb, then what is the role of the 転んだり in the grammatical sense? I understand that it is a verb which is transformed into 転んだり in a compound sentence but is it still considered a verb?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91416/5010

Answer (score 1):

たり is a conjunctive particle, rather than a part of a conjugated verb. Verbs can follow after conjunctive particles.