# たり・たり construction ending with です

Tags: grammar

after some research, I was wondering if you could help my understand the nuance in using です instead of する in a たり・たり construction, as for example below :

> 毎日テープを聴いていますか
>
> いいえ、聞いたり聞きなかったり**です**

Comment: Perhaps reading the first two paragraphs of this answer will help you: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/91419/45630